# Utility to buffer an unbounded amount of data in a pipeline?

Tags: pipe, io, buffer

Is there a utility that I can stick in a pipeline to decouple read and write speeds?

```
$ producer | buf | consumer
```

Basically, I want a utility `buf` that reads its input as fast as possible, storing it in memory so `consumer` can take its sweet time while `producer` runs as fast as possible.

Comment: I'd like to see such too

Comment: The `stdbuf` tool appears to be a `size` parameter. I'm not sure if it works though.

Answer (score 14):

The [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) (pipe viewer) utility can do this (with the `-B` option) and a lot more, including giving you progress reports.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an unbounded amount of data? As best as I can tell, I need to supply a number with -B and if the producer gets that far ahead of the consumer, the producer will slow down again. If you're in a situation where there are multiple consumers (`producer | tee >(pv -cB $SIZE | consumer1) | pv -cB $SIZE2 | consumer2`), this can cause slowdowns again.

Comment: I've used `pv` hundreds of times and never knew this. Very awesome, Thank you!

Comment: `pv -B 4096 -c -N in /dev/zero | pv -q -B 1000000000 | pv -B 4096 -c -N out -L 100k > /dev/null` - I expect both `pv`s on ends to be smooth (although one being 1GB ahead). It doesn't work this way, unlike with `mbuffer`

Answer (score 9):

you can use `dd`:

```
producer | dd obs=64K | consumer
```

It's available on every unix.

Comment: +1 for using standard utility, although `pv` is probably is probably nicer to use (shows progress).

Comment: Does that actually decouple the reading and writing speed? It seems like `dd` only stores one block at a time, so it would just delay everything by the amount of time it takes to produce the block size; please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, can this buffering be extended to unlimited size, or only whatever's entered for the block size?

Comment: @DanielH - it does now.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [mbuffer](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html).  It can buffer to memory or memory mapped file(`-t`/`-T`).

Comment: As I asked for the others, is there a way to tell it to buffer as much as is necessary, or does it have a maximum size? Is there a conceptual reason why most of these programs do have maximum sizes and don't, for example, use a linked list of smaller buffers (or any other arbitrary-size queue implementation)?

Comment: Probably to prevent out-of-memory errors. You can probably use an option to set a very large buffer (4GB or so) if you want so (try it).

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a negative answer. It appears that neither `dd`, nor `mbuffer`, nor even `pv` works is all cases, in particular if the rate of data generated by the producer can vary a lot. I give some testcases below. After typing the command, wait for about 10 seconds, then type `>` (to go to the end of the data, i.e. wait for the end of the input).

```
zsh -c 'echo foo0; sleep 3; \
        printf "Line %060d\n" {1..123456}; \
        echo foo1; sleep 5; \
        echo foo2' | dd bs=64K | less
```

Here, after typing `>`, one has to wait for 5 seconds, meaning that the producer (zsh script) has blocked before the `sleep 5`. Increasing the `bs` size to e.g. 32M doesn't change the behavior, though the 32MB buffer is large enough. I suspect that this is because `dd` blocks on output instead of going on with the input. Using `oflag=nonblock` is not a solution because this discards data.

```
zsh -c 'echo foo0; sleep 3; \
        printf "Line %060d\n" {1..123456}; \
        echo foo1; sleep 5; \
        echo foo2' | mbuffer -q | less
```

With `mbuffer`, the problem is that the first line (foo0) doesn't appear immediately. There doesn't seem to be any option to enable line-buffering on input.

```
zsh -c 'echo foo0; sleep 3; \
        printf "Line %060d\n" {1..123456}; \
        echo foo1; sleep 5; \
        echo foo2' | pv -q -B 32m | less
```

With `pv`, the behavior is similar to `dd`. Worse, I suspect that it does wrong things to the terminal since sometimes `less` can no longer receive input from the terminal; for instance, one cannot quit it with `q`.

Answer (score 0):

Nonstandard move: using socket buffers.

Example:

```
# echo 2000000000 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
$ socat -u system:'pv -c -N i /dev/zero',sndbuf=1000000000 - | pv -L 100k -c -N o > /dev/null
        i:  468MB 0:00:16 [ 129kB/s] [  <=>                        ]
        o: 1.56MB 0:00:16 [ 101kB/s] [       <=>                   ]
```

Implemented two additional tools for this: [buffered_pipeline](https://github.com/vi/udptap_tunnel/#buffered_pipeline) and [mapopentounixsocket](https://github.com/vi/udptap_tunnel/#mapopentounixsocket)

```
$ ./buffered_pipeline ! pv -i 10 -c -N 1 /dev/zero ! $((20*1000*1000)) ! pv -i 10 -L 100k -c -N 2 ! > /dev/zero
        1: 13.4MB 0:00:40 [ 103kB/s] [         <=>      ]
        2: 3.91MB 0:00:40 [ 100kB/s] [         <=>      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `pv` with `--buffer-size|-B` you probably want also use `--no-splice|-C` option to prevent from using `splice(2)` syscall.

From `pv` man pages:

```
-C, --no-splice
Never  use  splice(2),  even  if it would normally be possible.  The splice(2) system
call is a more efficient way of transferring data from or  to  a  pipe  than  regular
read(2)  and write(2), but means that the transfer buffer may not be used.  This pre‐
vents -A and -T from working, so if you want to use -A or -T then you  will  need  to
use  -C,  at  the  cost  of a small loss in transfer efficiency.  (This option has no
effect on systems where splice(2) is unavailable).
```

As far I'm aware `splice` is available on Linux therefore for using `pv` as a buffer there, the `-C` option should be used.

Therefore your final solution should be something like this:

```
$ producer | pv -C -B 1G | consumer
```

Comment: Seems to be not necessary in the more clearly written version of current Debian 12 where `-C` is *implied* when you use `-B`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. After checking https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml after version 1.6.19 it works as you said. But for older versions, this is still something to be aware of.