# What to use instead of `buffer` for 1GB buffer?

Tags: pipe, buffer

[buffer(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/buffer) seems to be old-ish and have hard-coded values preventing it to cache large amount of data.

```
$ buffer -m 1G
max_shmem 1 too low
   // it doesn't even understand gigabytes
$ buffer -m 1000M
Cannot handle that many blocks, aborting!
$ buffer -m 1000M -s 1m
blocksize 1048576 out of range
```

What do use instead?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you have a performance issue with `buffer`?

Comment: Actually I forgot that Mplayer has it's own adjustable buffer which can span gigabyte and tried to use `buffer` instead. I want to have `buffer` around as more generic solution for postponing processing of some data until enough accumulated.

Comment: If you are writing tar files, consider using star which comes with this functionality built in.

Answer (score 3):

Nonstandard move: using socket buffers.

Example:

```
# echo 2000000000 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
$ socat -u system:'pv -c -N i /dev/zero',sndbuf=1000000000 - | pv -L 100k -c -N o > /dev/null
        i:  468MB 0:00:16 [ 129kB/s] [  <=>                        ]
        o: 1.56MB 0:00:16 [ 101kB/s] [       <=>                   ]
```

Implemented two additional tools for this: [buffered_pipeline](https://github.com/vi/udptap_tunnel/#buffered_pipeline) and [mapopentounixsocket](https://github.com/vi/udptap_tunnel/#mapopentounixsocket)

```
$ ./buffered_pipeline ! pv -i 10 -c -N 1 /dev/zero ! $((20*1000*1000)) ! pv -i 10 -L 100k -c -N 2 ! > /dev/zero
        1: 13.4MB 0:00:40 [ 103kB/s] [         <=>      ]
        2: 3.91MB 0:00:40 [ 100kB/s] [         <=>      ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer for [Utility to buffer an unbounded amount of data in a pipeline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21918/20068) suggests using `pv -B $SIZE`.  The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html) indicates that it can handle larger buffer sizes.

> `-B BYTES, --buffer-size BYTES`
>
> Use a transfer buffer size of *`BYTES`* bytes. 
>   A suffix of "K", "M", "G", or "T" can be added
>   to denote kibibytes (*1024), mebibytes, and so on. 
>   The default buffer size is the block size
>   of the input file's filesystem multiplied by 32 (512 KiB max),
>   or 400 KiB if the block size cannot be determined.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
INPUT | { 
        mkdir  -p buf &&
        mount  -osize=1g -ttmpfs none buf || exit
        cat     >buf/...
        work_it <buf/...
        umount  buf
} | OUTPUT
```

For a ring-buffered loop possibly...

```sh
INPUT | { 
        mkdir  -p buf &&
        mount  -osize=1g -ttmpfs none buf &&
        while   dd bs=1 count=1 >buf/...  &&
                [ -s buf/... ]
        do      dd obs=64k   | 
                dd  bs=64k count=16383k >>buf/...
                work_it <buf/... 2>&3 
        done    3>&2 2>/dev/null          &&
        umount  buf
} | OUTPUT
```

Comment: How is tmpfs protected from overflow? I expect `INPUT` to block and wait if buffer is full.

Comment: @Vi. - That's what the pipe is for. `cat` will fill a file til it is full. Then it will stop. When it stops reading the pipe `INPUT` blocks.

Comment: What is `work_it`? `INPUT` is producer, `OUTPUT` is consumer. All the rest should be just buffering.

Comment: @Vi. the `buffer` command calls some other program, right? like `buffer my_command | OUTPUT`? I guess *`work_it`* is *`my_command`* - or it might just be `cat` and *`my_command`* will be fed 1g chunks of *`INPUT`* over the pipe and will block while the ring buffer collects it. whatever. i don't care. it's just an example of *how* it might be done. It can sometimes be nice, though, to have all of the advantages of a regular lseekable input file, as would be directly available to *`work_it`* if it were called repeatedly in the loop. however you like is ok w/ me.

Comment: No, `buffer` just reads input and writes it to output (like `cat`), but also remembers some data if output is slower than input. Compare `INPUT | cat | OUTPUT` (it would also do some buffering, but too little).

Comment: @Vi. `cat` doesn't buffer like that - well... *some* `cat`'s might, but even those should support an `-u`nbuffered switch according to POSIX. but most programs do buffer output - like around 4k or so, sometimes as much as 64k. i would consider it weird for them to do any more - at least linux kernels set the default atomic pipe read/write size at 64k.

Comment: Yes, `cat` is somewhat buffering because of pipe's buffer in kernel. `INPUT | OUTPUT` is one pipe, `INPUT | cat | OUTPUT` is two pipes, hence twice bigger buffer. I want to have big (gigabyte and more) buffer, that can, for example, house a couple of seconds of uncompressed video.

Comment: @Vi. - that's not how pipes work. the kernel will store only *up to* so much data in the pipe's buffer. but it releases that data as soon as it is read. `cat` reads input blocks as soon as they are available and writes them out in the same size it receives them.